# Output repeating four times

Tags: python-3.x

I'm new to python. I'm trying to make a project that orders and sets up combo meals. The problem is that when printing our the receipt, the receipt prints out four times. May I ask for help on how to fix this? I have tried rearranging the code, and trying multiple if statements but none have seem to work.

```
cart=[]
mains_total=[]
sides_total=[]
drinks_total=[]
sides=[]
drinks=[]
everything_total=[]

stuff={"steak": int(900), "salmon": int(850), "chicken": int(300)}
stuff2={"baked potato": int(80), "mashed potato": int(75), "steamed vegetables": int(50)}
stuff3={"ice tea": int(55), "root beer": int(60), "water": int(20)}

def system():


  print("Thanks for using our service, please select an option.\n(1) mains\n(2) sides\n(3) drinks\n(4) 
check-out\n(5) exit")
  print("Please order one of each category.")
  customer_input=int(input("Please type your answer here:"))
  if customer_input==1:
    print("steak=900") 
    print("salmon=850")
    print("chicken=300")
    global mains_order
    mains_order=input("What would you like to order?:")
    cart.append(mains_order)
    system()

  if customer_input==2:
    print("baked potato=80")
    print("mashed potato=75")
    print("steamed vegetables=50")
    global sides_order
    sides_order=input("What would you like to order?:")
    sides.append(sides_order)
    system()

  if customer_input==3:
    print("ice tea=55")
    print("root beer=60")
    print("water=20")
    global drinks_order
    drinks_order=input("What would you like to order?:")
    drinks.append(drinks_order)
    system()

  if customer_input==4:
    for items in cart:
      mains_total.append(stuff[items])
      global total_sum
      total_sum=sum(mains_total)
    for items in sides:
      sides_total.append(stuff2[items])
      global total_sides
      total_sides=sum(sides_total)
    for items in drinks:
      drinks_total.append(stuff3[items])
      global total_drinks
      total_drinks=sum(drinks_total)
    print(cart, total_sum)
    print(sides, total_sides)
    print(drinks, total_drinks)
    everything_total.append(total_sum)
    everything_total.append(total_sides)
    everything_total.append(total_drinks)
    global total_everything
    global total_everything
    total_everything=(sum(everything_total))
    print(total_everything)
    global price_input
    price_input=int(input("How much would you like to pay?:"))

  if '300' '75' '55' in everything_total:
    discounted_price=total_everything/100*10
    print("this is your discounted price:", discounted_price)

  if price_input<total_everything:
    print("Sorry you have insuficient funds. Please restate your order and try agian.")


  else:
    print(cart, total_sum)
    print(sides, total_sides)
    print(drinks, total_drinks)
    print("price total", total_everything)
    print("price paid", price_input)






system()
```

Comment: you're calling `system()` recursively depending on the user input, so all your print statements not guarded by if clauses will get executed for every recursive call to `system`

Comment: Consider visiting [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) for a style review.